# Unable to use recycler views in multiple tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tabs

I have three tabs.For testing purposes,I am setting the same fragment to all the three tabs.Fragment has a recycler view. I am able to view the recycler view only in first fragment.

Activity Code:

```
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TrialsFragment(), getString(R.string.camps));
        adapter.addFragment(new TrialsFragment(), getString(R.string.trials));
        adapter.addFragment(new TrialsFragment(), getString(R.string.events));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Fragment Code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        adapter = new TrialsRecyclerViewAdapter();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Adapter code:

```
public class TrialsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrialsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    String[] names = {"Sample Name","Sample Name","Sample Name","Sample Name","Sample Name"};
    String[] regNos ={"12345678","12345678","12345678","12345678","12345678"};

    @Override
    public TrialsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.trial_card, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TrialsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final CardView cardView = holder.cardView;

        TextView name = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.trial_name);
        TextView regNumber = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.trial_start_end);
        name.setText(names[position]);
        regNumber.setText(regNos[position]);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolder(CardView v)
        {
            super(v);
            cardView = v;
        }
    }
}
```

When the activity is started, RecyclerView is visible in first tab only. If I swipe the tabs, then it becomes visible in second tab only.

I observed the following error while debugging it:

> No adapter attached; skipping layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler);
```

This is very wrong. Move your logic from `onActivityCreated()` into `onViewCreated()`, and get the fragment's *own* `RecyclerView`. Each fragment should be creating its own `RecyclerView` in `onCreateView()`, which will be the contents of that page of the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thanks a lot..! It worked. Will accept answer after 10 minutes.